# What exactly should I change when performing image filtering using convolution

Tags: c++, image-processing, cimg

So I'm supposed to write this image processing program using convolution. This is the header:CImg FilterImage(const CImg& image,const CImg& filter) and we can only access width, height, depth and spectrum. I understand how convolution works but I don't know what should I change. Should I change the spectrum? Also is it just one giant method? I'm very confused by the setup of this thing. Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. Is it? Were you given instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds confused. I think you are trying to use **CImg** although you haven't tagged it as such, to perform an image convolution.

So, I think you want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    // 9x9 simple box filter (all coefficients are 1)
    CImg<unsigned char> box(9,9,1,1,1);
    CImg<unsigned char> image("start.pgm");

    CImg<unsigned short> result;
    result=image.get_convolve(box);
    (image,result).display();
}
```

The start image is shown on the left and the box-filtered image on the right:

[image]

Comment: Yea but I should implement the convolution method I can't use the method in the library. So i have to change the pixel values myself... I'm just not sure what value should I change is it spectrum or some other values?

Comment: Mmmm... the spectrum is just the number of channels in the image, 1 for greyscale or 3 for colour. You'll need to write a `for_xy()` loop to do a convolution.